# Sending AJAX post on button click with button class and text change

Tags: jquery, ajax

Without the AJAX part everything works perfectly, but after I added AJAX part
to code nothing works. I'm not good with jQuery and JS so I've got no idea what causes that issue. Can anyone show me the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggleClassWorktime").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
      $(this).removeClass("btn-success");

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: {
            WorktimeAction: "START"
          },
          dataType: "json",
          encode: true,
          success: function(response) {
            $('.WorktimeText').html(response);
          });
      });
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-success");
      $(this).removeClass("btn-danger");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
          WorktimeAction: "STOP"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
        success: function(response) {
          $('.WorktimeText').html(response);
        });
      });
    }

    $(this).text(function(i, v) {
      return v === 'START' ? 'STOP' : 'START'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console? What error does it show?

Comment: I've formatted your code in a snippet where you can see you have some syntax issues due to extra/missing parentheses and braces. I'd suggest correcting those.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point, a had to much braces. Thank You!